# Android 11 : FFmpeg binary not found error

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, android-10.0, android-11, android-ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg to create photo to video

Getting File not found error.

```
Java.io.Exception /Data/user/0/package/files/ffmpeg file not found.
```

File Location: **Assets** -> **armeabi-v7a** -> **ffmpeg**

Works okay when using Android 10 or below, but not with SDK version above 10.

Does anyone have a solution? If yes, then please guide.

Comment: What exact app are you using? If it's an app you're developing, what library and code are you calling for this conversion?